# How can update each row of a table based on two columns of it's previous row?

Tags: sqlite, join, sum, sql-update, window-functions

I have following table:

| Id | offset | length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5000 | 0 | 5 |
| 5001 | 5 | 5 |
| 5002 | 10 | 4 |
| 5003 | 14 | 4 |
| 5010 | 23 | 5 |
| 5011 | 28 | 5 |

Offset value in each row is based on summation of offset and length of previous row.
As you can see, 6 rows have been deleted between forth and fifth rows and I need to update again offset column based on regular way. My desired output would be as follow:

| Id | offset | length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5000 | 0 | 5 |
| 5001 | 5 | 5 |
| 5002 | 10 | 4 |
| 5003 | 14 | 4 |
| 5010 | 18 | 5 |
| 5011 | 23 | 5 |

Is there a pure update SQL statement to achieve this in sqlite?
I Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ you can use the [`UPDATE ... FROM...`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) syntax with `SUM()` window function:

```
UPDATE tablename AS t1
SET offset = t2.offset
FROM (
  SELECT Id, SUM(length) OVER (ORDER BY Id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) offset
  FROM tablename 
) AS t2
WHERE t2.Id = t1.Id AND t2.offset IS NOT NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/733JZUxbhdC).

For previous versions use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE tablename AS t1
SET offset = COALESCE(
  (SELECT SUM(t2.length) FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.Id < t1.Id), 
  t1.offset
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b4f162698a510e4af70774c61ba0d886).

Comment: I came across @forpas another requirement. There is another column in table named listNumber ranging from 1 to 5. How can I change your great suggested update to apply it separately on each listNumber? I mean grouping update based on listNumber.

Comment: @hamid if I understand what you mean by grouping, change the 1st query to: `...OVER (PARTITION BY listNumber ORDER BY Id...)` or the 2nd query to: `...WHERE t2.listNumber = t1.listNumber AND t2.Id < t1.Id...`

Comment: So sorry @forpas for another interrupt. I need the offset of first row in each listNumber be 0. During deletion process, it may happen bunch of first records in a listNumber get removed. Is there a way to include this requirement in your update statement?

Comment: @hamid check this: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/22BB5Btah1W and this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3da417083dba83c2fbe08c9633968450 where you should also use list Number just like before.

Comment: Sorry @forpas, I forgot to mention that my sqlite version is under 3.33. So I can't use UPDATE... FROM style.  Could you please provide the solution in correlated subquery format?

Comment: @hamid this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3da417083dba83c2fbe08c9633968450